# "for in" loop --- object syntax

Tags: javascript, object, undefined-behavior, for-in-loop

when I write

```
for (var x in object) { 
  console.log(object[x]) 
}
```

it works fine!
But if I replace `object[x]` with `object.x` it doesn't work, it returns `undefined`.

---

console-logging both `object[propriety1]` and `object.propriety1` outside of `for in` loop works fine for both of them.

Any explainations?!

```js
var object = {
         propriety1 : "value1",
         propriety2 : "value2",
         propriety3 : "value3"
}
     
for (var x in object) {
  console.log(object.x);
}
     
console.log(object.propriety1);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a for loop it gives you all the keys of an object.

object [key] is the syntax to get respective values

```js
var object = {
         propriety1 : "value1",
         propriety2 : "value2",
         propriety3 : "value3"
     }
     
     for (var x in object){
         
         console.log(x);// gives you keys of object
         console.log(object[x]);//syntax to get value corresponding to a key
     }
     
     console.log(object.propriety1);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `x` is just the name of the variable in the `for` loop

The value of `x` will be "property1", then "property2" and then "property3" as the for loop advances

2. `object[x]` means "get a property of `object` whose name is contained in the variable `x`". It is equivalent to `object["property1"]`, etc
3. `object.x` is meaningless, unless your object has a property with name "x"

Answer (score 0):

The Reason for this quite simple Actually.

When we use for-in Loop to iterate over an object, the variable gets assigned the string values(**i.e variable x in the above example gets string values**), and when we try to access object.x inside loop what actually happens is **object."property1"** and there is no property named **"property1"** (notice the quotes) in the object.

Comment: how about when we try to access object[x] ?? 

doesn't it inject the quotes inside the brackets too ?

Comment: When we use the [key] syntax, The JS Engine always convert the key passed into string. So it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

When you write `object.x` the compiler is looking for a property `x` but it doesn't find it and so it returns `undefined`, because there is no `x` property.

With `object[x]` the compiler is looking for a property in `object` with the *value* that `x` stores.

### Example

```js
var object = {
  propriety1 : "value1",
  propriety2 : "value2",
  propriety3 : "value3"
}

// object doesn't have the property x --> returns undefined
console.log('first', object.x)

// object has propriety1 so it returns it value
console.log('second', object.propriety1)
     
for (var x in object) {
  // looks for the value of x in object
  console.log(object[x]);
  
  // looks for the property x in object --> undefined
  console.log(object.x)  
}
```